# Firebase Storage request params

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am using Firebase Storage in an Android app and I am using [getBytes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference.html#public-methods) method to get the file.

I want to set a [param to the request](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/secure-files#request_evaluation) but I am unable to find any method to add the params.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These params are set automatically on download (we build all the download URLs for you), so we're totally abstracted away networking. What additional query params would you like to add?

A better way of doing this might be [attaching custom metadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#add_file_metadata) to your file and then [checking that custom metadata in your rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/storage/#properties_1).

Comment: I want to secure the file using a secret key so only people with the secret key can access the file. I have successfully set the secret key in the file metadata. The idea is to compare the metadata key with the one from the request param.

Comment: This functionality is already built in to Firebase Storage: we offer public URLs with a signed token in the query param, meaning that only developers with that token can access the file, and we also offer private, internal URLs that are guarded with Firebase Storage Security Rules (https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security). For user based security (like above), check out the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/user-security